# At which frequency is the /etc/profile file modified by the system

Tags: upgrade

I need to modify the `/etc/profile` file on a server that's in production. My fear is that, when I upgrade the server's OS, the change I made to the file would be overwritten. Is my fear justified? I run on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never. Well it will when you re-install your system. Never during an upgrade or update. You can expect a big fat warning prior to the installation if `/etc/profile` would become obsolete.

`/etc` is used for host specific files. So configuration files.

---

Addition. There are some alternatives:

- `/etc/profile.d/`: Contains system-wide configuration files for specific programs
- `~/.profile`: 
  Insert user specific configuration for login shells here

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Can you send me the link of an official documentation that specifies this?

Comment: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html  is the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard we follow. Well... some consider it a guideline ;)

Comment: Are you sure that `/etc/profile.local` is supported in Ubuntu? I couldn't found any documentation.

Comment: Not sure. I removed it since I can't find it either. `/etc/profile` gets updated on suse so I am wondering if Ubuntu would do the same. I never noticed it got changed and I update/upgrade a lot of servers but I am in doubt  ;-) I have a search running for `.local` so I might come back with more ;-)